# Como formatar uma string com 3 casas?

Tags: delphi

Tenho um código que concatena os resultados digitados em edits, estou atribuindo um 0 para cada leitura para os valores fiquem assim:

Resultado: 030/060/090/

Mais quando eu tenho um valor que já tem 3 casas decimais então eu gostaria de manter apenas 3 casas.

Resultado: 030/060/090/0120/

```html
procedure TfrmCadastroPedido.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
     i: integer;
begin
      //fazer a leitura de componentes edits com um nome especifico
      for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
      begin

         if (Copy((Components[i].Name),1,7) = 'edPrazo') and (Components[i].Tag = 1) then
         begin
            if TEdit(Components[i]).Text <> '0' then
             begin
                PrazoParcelasNF :=  PrazoParcelasNF + '0' + TEdit(Components[i]).Text  + '/' ;
             end;
         end;
      end;

       Memo1.Lines.Add(PrazoParcelasNF);

end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta adicionar :

```
PrazoParcelasNF :=  PrazoParcelasNF + Format('%3.3d', [StrToInt(TEdit(Components[i]).Text)]) + '/';
```